# The quantum natural gradient descent problem

Tags: quantum-algorithms

I was wondering if you could help me understand Quantum Natural Gradient Descent. I've been reading some papers related to it, such as "Quantum Natural Gradient" by [James Stokes el al.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1909.02108.pdf) and some examples of QNGD (Quantum Natural Gradient Descent) by [Naoki Yamamoto](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1909.05074v1.pdf). However, I'm having a hard time understanding these concepts, and I have some arguments around the context of Quantum Natural Gradient Descent that may be wrong in some way. Please don't hesitate to correct me if that's the case.

I have a couple of arguments that I would like to share:

**The first argument:**

In James Stokes's paper, he and his partner introduced the Fubini-Study metric, and in equation (18), it is declared that we can approximate all off-diagonal terms to zeros. This doesn't make sense to me because when I calculated the equation of G_ij with i and j not in the same layer, I got:

\begin{equation}
G_{ij} = <{\psi_l}|K_iU^\dagger_{(l:l']}K_j|\psi_{l'}> - <{\psi_l}|K_iU_{(1:l]}|0> <0|U^\dagger_{[1:l']}K_j|\psi_{l'}> \end{equation}

where l and l' are indices relating to the layer of i and j. Therefore, it is clear that the equation is not equal to zero. Additionally, in Naoki Yamamoto's paper, when they calculate the Fubini-Study metric for the parameter circuit as shown in the attached images,

$\hspace{4cm}$[image]

it can be seen that in simple cases, the off-diagonal Fubini-Study metric is not equal to zero. Although this is just an approximation, even if $\theta_1$, $\theta_2$, $\theta_3$, and $\theta_4$ are near zero, what about the $cos(2*\theta_1)$ term? It will approximate to $1-2*\theta_1$, so I think we need to consider this more carefully.

**The second argument:**

In equation (9) of James Stokes's paper, I'm not sure how they end up with equation (10) with g as the Fubini-Study metric. As I understand it, the Fubini-Study metric they want to measure is equation (14) in [Andrea Mari el al.'s paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2008.06517.pdf):

\begin{equation}
g_{ij}(\theta) = -\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \theta^i \partial \theta^j}|<\psi(\theta')|\psi(\theta)>|^2|_{\theta'=\theta}
\end{equation}

However, my question comes from James Stokes's paper, and what I understand is that the Fubini-Study metric in this case should be calculated for the Loss function in equation (9) of James Stokes's paper, which should be equal to:

\begin{equation}
g_{ij}(\theta) = -\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 L}{\partial \theta^i \partial \theta^j}
\end{equation}

These questions may be simple for some of you, but they are new to me. I would greatly appreciate any help from the community.

Thank you very much!